# Iterating through an array in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, resultset

I have a model where I query the subjects a student is enrolled in. A student can have a subject from zero to any positive number. I will then pass it to the view where I will make a div for each subject. How do you suggest I will do it? Here is the code for my model:

```
public function getAllSubjects($username){
        $this->db->select('student.username, subjects.subject_name, teacher.firstname as TeachersFirstName, teacher.surname as TeacherSurname');
        $this->db->from('users student');
        $this->db->join('student_subjects', 'student.username = student_subjects.student_username', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('subjects', 'student_subjects.subject_id = subjects.subject_id', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('users teacher', 'subjects.teacher_username = teacher.username', 'inner');
        $this->db->where('student.username', $username);
        $studentSubjQuery = $this->db->get('users');
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Now I haven't tried anything yet. I simply don't know how I will iterate through the array once I passed the resulting array to the view. I have done it in the past. I used foreach to loop through the result. I did it in vanilla php and the view is mixed with the php code - which is ugly. I am echoing s for every result in the array. Now, I want to do this in codeigniter but, being new to the MVC framework, I really have no idea how to do this.

Comment: The problem statement seems a bit vague..what have you tried and what did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the results either as an object:

```
foreach ($studentSubjQuery->result() as $row) {

}
```

or as an array:

```
foreach ($studentSubjQuery->result_array() as $row) {

}
```

Comment: Will I do this in the controller, view or the model? I don't know how I will use that in my View.

Comment: Usually you would do this in the model...unless you want different outcomes in different controllers. The easiest would be to just return the result `return $studentSubQuery->result();` (or `result_array()`)

Comment: Then, after calling the function, I will pass it to the view through the $data, right? Then, how will I create a div for each result in the view?

Comment: That depends on what data is in the database. If you return the results from the model to the controller, put it in `$data['sqlResults']` (or whatever you want to call it), then just do a `foreach ($sqlResults as $row) `in the view. If you're unsure what the about how your data is structured just use `echo '<pre>';var_dump($sqlReults);exit('</pre>')` or http://raveren.github.io/kint/

Comment: Is it okay if I will echo html tags in the foreach statement? It seems like against the purpose of using MVC framework? Any other ways to do this?

Comment: That's exactly what a view file is for. The whole "what should go where" with MVC can be grey at times, but something like that is absolutely fine.

Comment: If this has answered your question would you mark it as complete? :)